# white-space: nowrap generating extra empty space at the bottom on Google Chrome mobile

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile

When applying `white-space: nowrap`, on Google Chrome mobile it generates some extra empty space at the bottom of the page causing vertical scroll to an empty area.

For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      p {
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Maiores magnam
      voluptatum eum laborum quo nihil distinctio hic nulla, libero aliquam
      consequatur. Architecto quod doloremque nostrum, vel perspiciatis ipsam
      quia at.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When looking at the page on a mobile device on Google Chrome, or when using Google Chrome's dev tools, it generates some extra empty space at the bottom of the page. I have tried applying `height` and `min-height` to the body but no matter what value I use the space at the bottom persist, for example:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here is a gif of the issue recorded on Google Chrome dev tools:

[image: white-space: nowrap extra empty space]

I check on Firefox and it does not generate the extra empty space. On Google Chrome desktop there is no extra empty space generated at the bottom.

Any ideas what's could be the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: It looks like it’s 100% of the width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in chromes emulation.  If you shrink the window down (instead of emulation) it does not scroll vertically.  I also does not scroll vertically on my Android.

If you want a much more accurate emulation of other devices, [www.browserstack.com](http://www.browserstack.com) is a very good solution. I have no affiliation with that website, or any company backing it.

Comment: Thanks! I tested on two Android devices and in both got the vertical scroll, was pretty sure that it is a Google Chrome mobile issue and not an emulator issue. I tested with this page https://www.mauriciorobayo.com/nowrap/ and some other with similar results. Anyhow, will accept you answer as it seems there is no workaround and I agree with you that most probably it is a bug. What you describe is exactly the behavior that I got on my tests and that already reported on the question, although on my tests it extended to Android devices.